# Giving access to everything within S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

Does anyone know if I can use a wildcard and give access to everything within S3 bucket?
Instead of adding every location explicitly like I am currently doing?

```
const policyDoc = new PolicyDocument({
  statements: [
    new PolicyStatement({
      sid: 'Grant role to read/write to S3 bucket',
      resources: [
        `${this.attrArn}`,
        `${this.attrArn}/*`,
        `${this.attrArn}/emailstore`,
        `${this.attrArn}/emailstore/*`,
        `${this.attrArn}/attachments`,
        `${this.attrArn}/attachments/*`
      ],
      actions: ['s3:*'],
      effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      principals: props.allowedArnPrincipals
    })
   ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```json
      resources: [
        `${this.attrArn}`,
        `${this.attrArn}/*`
      ],
```

The first one gives permission for actions on the bucket itself (eg ListBucket), while `/*` gives permission for actions *inside* the bucket (eg GetObject).